# How to make a variable change in one directive to get reflected in another directve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How do i change the value of `bar` from `directive2` so that it is reflected in `directive1`

If i make the `scope:false` it is happening.
Is there any other way, to make this happen.(because in the code i am writting , i cannot make `scope:false`).
My basic requirement is to make one directive to talk to another.
[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/PXUkKl9UtvHE8HxHrvhD?p=preview) you can try the **plunkr** version of the below code

**HTML snippet**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  this is directive1: <div directive1></div>.<br/>
  this is directive2: <div directive2></div>.
</body>
```

**JS snippet**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('directive1', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        replace: true,
        template: '<span>{{bar}}</span>'
    }

    });

app.directive('directive2', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope:{


      },
       replace: true,
       link:function(s,e,a){
         s.bar = "Changed value";
       },
       template: '<b>{{bar}}</b>'
  }

});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.bar ="original value";
});
```

Comment: The second directive should use require to get a reference to the first directive's controller. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-

Comment: @JBNizet but those two directive should be nested

Comment: That's precisely what require is for.

Comment: @dreamer could you please update your plunkr with code?

Comment: I have already read, that the directives should be nested, if `require` is to be used. So i know that. But in this scenario, which is a completly valid situation, how do i get what i want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use `bar` inside your isolate scope, that will do two way binding with your variable which is assigned to `bar` attribute, That means change inside a directive on `bar` variable will reflect the changes on controller scope variable.

**Markup**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  this is directive1: <div directive1></div>.
  <br />
  this is directive2: <div directive2 bar="bar"></div>.
</body>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('directive2', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope:{
        'bar': '=' //<-- Change here
      },
       replace: true,
       link:function(s,e,a){
         s.bar = "Changed value";
       },
       template: '<b>{{bar}}</b>'
  }

});
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/lwm8VhtoF2eNO5aJcsQj?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

I have modified your code in [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/p2p4g8?p=preview)

Share the variable in both directives by passing it as '=' in the scope, changing it in one directive will change it in the the other.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  this is directive1: <div directive1 bar="bar"></div>.
  <br />
  this is directive2: <div directive2 bar="bar"></div>.
</body>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive('directive1', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope:{bar:'='},
    replace: true,
    template: '<span>{{bar}}</span>'
}

});

app.directive('directive2', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope:{bar:'='},
    replace: true,
    link:function(s,e,a){
      s.bar = "Changed value";
    },
   template: '<b>{{bar}}</b>'
}

});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.name = 'World';
 $scope.bar ="original value";
});
```

Comment: same as what pankaj has posted, except for the passing of variable into `directive1` , which is actually not required in this case.Anyways thanks for the answer

Comment: @dreamer its actually copy and paste type of mine answer

Comment: @pankajparkar:can u take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29874648/4112077)

Answer (score 0):

If they don't share the same $scope, the only way is using angularjs [events](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope).

In first directive you put:

```
$rootScope.$on('myEvent', function (event, data) {
  $scope.bar = data.bar;
});
```

In the second one when bar change:

```
$scope.$emit('myEvent', {bar: bar});
```

Taking into account that are directives completely unrelated.

Comment: i am kinda beginner here.So it would be very helpful, if you could share the code with the above lines added. thanks in advance

Comment: In your case as you have the var bar in the controller $scope you can take advantage of two-way databind like in other answers. If you didn't have this var in the $scope, for instance, each directive in different controllers, your options would be $rootScope or events that I prefer.