# AngularJS : how to reflect a variable change in one directive into another directive while using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

In **first case**: I implemented a directive `directive2` that will change `bar` value which will also get reflected in `directive1`.
Here u can find the **[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/PXUkKl9UtvHE8HxHrvhD?p=preview)** (1st case)
In **second case**:I implemented a directive `directive2`, with `ng-repeat` used along with this directive that changes `bar` value and this is ***supposed to get reflected*** in `directive1`.
Here u can find the **[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/PejKbBM0wOKXKPnpWrvY?p=preview)** for `directive2` with `ng-repeat`(2nd case)

**How i expect it to work**: i want the `bar` in `directive1` to change according to the change in `directive2`

**My question:** 1st case is working the way i want. In the 2nd case my `bar` value  in `directive1` is not changing according to changes made in `directive2`.
My assumption is that using `ng-repeat` is creating multiple scopes and hence not working the way i want.

How do i solve this?

**HTML snippet**(2nd case)

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    this is directive1: <directive1></directive1>
    <br />
    <div ng-repeat="item in [1,2]"> 
        this is directive2 for ng-repeat {{item}}
        <directive2 bar="bar"></directive2>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JS snippet**(2nd case)

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('directive1', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',

        replace: true,
        template: '<div><span>{{bar}}</span></div>'
    }

 });

app.directive('directive2', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope:{
        bar:"="
      },
       replace: true,
       link:function(s,e,a){
         s.bar = "Changed value";
       },
       template: '<div><b>{{bar}}</b></div>'
  }

});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.bar ="original value";
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have correctly guessed it! This is happening because of child scopes created by `ng-repeat`.

When you are creating a isolated scope with `bar` dependency the set operation on `bar` is setting the bar value on parent scope. In case of ng-repeat the parent scope is the `ng-repeat` scope and hence this behaviour.

Use a object instead of string to pass the string reference around and it will work. Check my plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/JCQsIXzRv9FUNfJwhOAB?p=preview

Set bar variable as

```
$scope.data={};
$scope.data.bar ="original value";
```

User directive like

`<directive2 bar="data.bar"></directive2>`